# Difficulty powering off Desktop Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and it went very smoothly. Reboot - no problem but if I select power off it either hangs displaying a logo or gets stuck in a loop with error messages: I took a photo of the screen which starts:

```
usb 1-9 hub failed to enable device error -108

usb 1-9 device not accepting address 5 error -108
 
usb usb1-port9: couldn't allocate usb device

sr 2:0:0:0 tag#21 timing out command 120s

INFO task systemd-shutdown:1 blocked for more than 120seconds

   Not tainted 5.4.0-54-generic #60-ubuntu
```

and a whole lot more after a time out.
starting with

Call trace:

a load more stuff then:
including Code: `Bad RIP value`
Suggestions please?

Comment: These errors all look like they have to do with a USB device.  For diagnostic purposes, using process of elimination, I suggest that you remove all non-essential USB devices prior to booting and see if the problem still exists when you try to shut down.

Comment: 20.04 confirmed and corrected.
Prior to upgrade it all worked so unlikely any USB device is at fault. I have tried unplugging USB devices as suggested and it does change the power down sequence - sometimes error messages sometimes I get a logo but it doesn't shut down.